# Is H a subgroup of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let K be a subgroup of a group G and H be a subgroup of K. Is it true that H is a subgroup of G? Justify.
It is obvious that H is a subgroup (like subset of a subset is a subset of the original set). How will I justify this?

Comment: Since a subgroup is a subset, which is a group, this is really obvious due to the transitivity of the subset-relation.

Comment: Just refer to the definitions.

Comment: $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $\forall$ $a, b \in H$ $ab^{-1} \in H$. As you can see this doesn't depend on whether you have a $K$ in $G$ and $H$ in $K$. The group operation you use is anyway the same on all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $K$, it is closed under multiplication and inversion and $e \in H$. Since $H \subset G$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.